# Simplest way to find the difference between two dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, multi-index

I'm trying to find the difference between two dates in a multi index data frame that is the result of a pivot table operation.

The data frame contains three columns. The first is a `measurement` the second is the `end date` and the third is the `start date`.

I've been able to successfully add a third multi index column to the data frame but only to make the result of reach cell zero

Pt["min"]["start_date"] = 0 but when I try to subtract the two dates I get a string error and appending `.Dt.Days` to the end of each column results in an error as well.

What is the simplest way to find the difference in days between two dates in a multi index pandas data frame?

Answer (score 2):

You can select `Multiindex` in columns by `tuples` and subtract columns:

```
print (df)
     a                        
  meas         end       start
0    7  2015-04-05  2015-04-01
1    8  2015-04-07  2015-04-02
2    9  2015-04-14  2015-04-04

#if dtypes not datetime
df[('a','end')] = pd.to_datetime(df[('a','end')])
df[('a','start')] = pd.to_datetime(df[('a','start')])

df[('a','diff')] = df[('a','end')] - df[('a','start')]

print (df)
     a                              
  meas        end      start    diff
0    7 2015-04-05 2015-04-01  4 days
1    8 2015-04-07 2015-04-02  5 days
2    9 2015-04-14 2015-04-04 10 days
```

---

If need output in [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df[('a','diff')] = (df[('a','end')] - df[('a','start')]).dt.days
print (df)
     a                           
  meas        end      start diff
0    7 2015-04-05 2015-04-01    4
1    8 2015-04-07 2015-04-02    5
2    9 2015-04-14 2015-04-04   10
```